# Java Login System: Creating a new User in a login system

Tags: java

I have created a login system with some "preset" users. I would like to alter my code to be able to create new user(s) inside the system and add them to my user list. How can I do this? I am a beginner in Java so help will be appreciated.

LoginSystem class:

```
    package logpack;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LoginSystem {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public boolean run() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        String inpUser = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        String inpPass = keyboard.nextLine(); // gets input from user

        boolean loginSuccess = false;

        for (User temp : users) {
            if (inpUser.equals(temp.getUsername()) && inpPass.equals(temp.getPassword())) {

                System.out.println("Welcome " + temp.getName() + " to the System.");
                loginSuccess = true;
                break;

            } else {
                loginSuccess = false;
            }
        }

        if (loginSuccess == false) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input, Try again.");
        }
        return loginSuccess;

    }

    public void saveUser(User US) {
        users.add(US);
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

}
```

User class:

```
    package logpack;

    public class User {
    String name;
    String username;
    String password;

    public User(String name, String username, String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password; 
        this.name = name;
    }
     protected String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     protected void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name; 
     }

     protected String getUsername() {
         return username;
     }
     protected void setUsername (String username) {
         this.username = username;

     }

     protected String getPassword() {
         return password;
     }
     protected void setPassword (String password) {
         this.password = password;
     }

}
```

RunClass class(the one I have to alter to create a kind of "register" system):

```
package logpack;


public class RunClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LoginSystem LGS = new LoginSystem();
        System.out.println("Enter username: ");


        ////////
        User u1 = new User("Daria", "Daria5", "12345");
        User u2 = new User("Bob", "Bob8989 ", "Bob64748od7");
        User u3 = new User("Samanta", "Sam764", "678303");
        User u4 = new User("Dog", "Doggy998621", "C6574");
        User u5 = new User("Doughnut", "DBghf", "pae102938");


        LGS.saveUser(u1);
        LGS.saveUser(u2);
        LGS.saveUser(u3);
        LGS.saveUser(u4);
        LGS.saveUser(u5);
        ///////
        /*Can you replace this section above with a loop and method that asks
        * the user if they want to create a new user account? As many as they want?
        * This is inefficient as we have to write many lines to create many users.
        * It does mean that we always have users to start with to simulate
        * having a save file.
        */

        LGS.run();
        //System.out.println("User list: "+LGS.users);

    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In the LoginSystem you could add the ADD or DELETE or MODIFY method (like the existing "RUN" method) and save the user list in a file (as ObjectStream) and then in the "RunClass" you can ADD, DELETE, MODIFY the users as you like.

Answer (score 0):

In your main class, instead of prompting the user to enter username, prompt the user with a list of options and the user either select login or registration, e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a scanner to read the command-line input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int optionSelected;

    do {
        System.out.println("Select 1 for Login");
        System.out.println("Select 2 for User Registration");
        System.out.println("Select 3 to Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter selected option: ");
        optionSelected = scanner.nextInt();

        if(optionSelected == 1){
            // proceed with login
            System.out.println("Login in progress\n");
        } else if (optionSelected == 2){
            // proceed with registration
            System.out.println("Registration in progress\n");
        }
    } while (optionSelected != 3);
}
```

It is not the best code in the world, but it will help you out. For now there are only 3 options, later you can add more options.